# Array Values in Cocoa App - Initializer not constant error

Tags: cocoa, xcode, timer, initializer

Im trying to set an array for a timer program im writing in xcode. the values are in seconds, and what i want is to have a button in the interface builder that starts a timer with that number of seconds. This is the struct im trying to declare to provide the times in a .h header file. its just an array with 2 arrays in it, that i could call with @collegeTimes.constructive or something similar.

Thanks in advance!

```
- (NSDictionary *)debateTimes;
 id debateTimes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   @"540", @"constructive",
   @"360", @"rebuttal",
   @"180", @"cx",
   @"600", @"prep",
     nil], @"collegeTimes",
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   @"480", @"constructive",
   @"300", @"rebuttal",
   @"180", @"cx",
   @"480", @"prep",
     nil], @"hsTimes",
                   nil]; \\error is called here.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is the struct im trying to declare to provide the times in a .h header file

This is the problem. You can not create constant `NSDictionary` objects (or most other `NS` objects, for that matter) outside of a function. One way to do what wou want would be as follows:

> **SomeThing.h**

```
@interface SomeThing : NSObject
{
    ...
}
+ (NSDictionary *)debateTimes;
@end
```

> **SomeThing.m**

```
static NSDictionary * staticDebateTimes = nil;
@implementation SomeThing
...
+ (NSDictionary *)debateTimes
{
    if (staticDebateTimes == nil)
    {
        staticDebateTimes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:...
    }
    return staticDebateTimes;
}
@end
```

This code would now be used externally as follows:

```
NSDictionary * debateTimes = [SomeThing debateTimes];
```

Comment: +1 also preferable to place the static inside `+[SomeThing debateTimes]`, when possible: `static NSDictionary* const staticDebateTimes = CreateDebateTimesDictionary();`

Comment: @Justin: You know, that makes sense, but I have never seen it done inside the method body. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: it reduces the chance of error/reuse/misuse/collisions because of locality. it also initializes on entry, you may remove the nil-check. it's another flavor of how to use static data - which is best comes down to context -- case-by-case. slightly cleaner, and a good bit of added safety.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an objective-c object to a variable outside of a function. When a variable is assigned outside a function, its value becomes part of the executable. Since the value of the pointer to a object is not known until runtime, you cannot assign the object until it is created. (Constant NSStrings are an exception to this as they are also part of the executable)

The best way to store a structure like this would be to use an array of c structures.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;

    NSTimeInterval constructive;
    NSTimeInterval rebuttal;
    NSTimeInterval cx;
    NSTimeInterval prep;
} DebateTime;
DebateTime[2] = {{"collegeTimes", 540, 360, 180, 600},
                 {"hsTimes", 480, 300, 180, 480}};
```

You can also change the name and time intervals to constant strings if you wish.